# How to bring up an interface using Ansible 'nmcli' module?

Tags: ansible, nmcli

I can create an interface with something like:

```yaml
- name: create dummy interface
  community.general.nmcli:
    type: dummy
    conn_name: '{{ item.conn_name }}'
    ifname: '{{ item.ifname }}'
    ip6: '{{ item.ip6 }}'
    state: present
  with_items:
    - '{{ nmcli_dummy }}'
```

But if in the server I put the interface down: `ifconfig dummy0 down`, what parameter or options could be used to manage the interface state, for example `up` or `down`?

Answer (score 0):

For a connection in example named `eth1` the equivalents for `show`, `up` and `down` are

```bash
nmcli con show eth1
nmcli con up eth1
nmcli con down eth1
```

Whereby in [`nmcli`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmcli_module.html) module are certain [Parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmcli_module.html#parameters) for

> *Manage the network devices. Create, modify and manage various connection and device type e.g., ethernet, teams, bonds, vlans etc.*

a parameter for bringing a network interface up or down is not explicit named.

This might leave one to think to workaround it with

```yaml
- name: Brings the interface up or down
  command: 
    cmd: "nmcli con {{ CMD }} eth1"
  register: nmcli_con_cmd_result
```

as this is almost [what the module code is doing](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/nmcli.py#L1920) under the hood.

However, according the [NetworkManager / ansible-network-role](https://github.com/NetworkManager/ansible-network-role#state) it seems that the paramter `state` can have more values. In your case you could first check how it is implemented there in the project role and test after with [`state: up`](https://github.com/NetworkManager/ansible-network-role#state-up) and [`state: down`](https://github.com/NetworkManager/ansible-network-role#state-down) accordingly.

Regarding

> *I can create an interface with ...*

it seems that [if connection becomes created it is brought up](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/nmcli.py#L1968), as well [if connection becomes removed, it is brought down](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/nmcli.py#L2343) before.

**Further Documentation**

- [Configuring IP Networking with `nmcli`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configuring_ip_networking_with_nmcli)
- [NetworkManager Project - Ansible Network Role](https://github.com/NetworkManager/ansible-network-role)
- [`community.general/plugins/modules/nmcli.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/nmcli.py)